# Browser back button not working properly on router query param change

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a simple route definition:

```js
    {
        path: 'customers',
        name: 'customers',
        component: Customers,
        props: true
    }
```

To start with, I am on the general /customers route.
But I can use query params on this route, and react on changes to load the corresponding data:

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'customers', query: { customerId: '123' } });
```

```js
@Watch('$route.query.customerId')
customerIdChanged() {
   this.loadCustomer($route.query.customerId);
}
```

This works as intended, but let´s say i push three different customerId´s to this router, and now want to go back in browser history and load the previous customers one by one. I can´t because a query change is not considered a "real" url change. So when I push back, I get routed back to the initial /customers route.

How to make these query changes count as real url changes so I can use the back button?
I could maintain my own browser history stack, but I would rather not, and think there is a more "official" solution?

Thanks!

---- UPDATE ----

I actually had an error in my code. Before i pushed to the route, i replaced the route with /customer. And then pushed the customer query route. This was why the back navigation did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [dynamic matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)? You could use:

```
{
    path: 'customers/:id',
    name: 'customers',
    component: Customers,
    props: true
}
```

---

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'customers', params: { id: '123' } });
```